# assetmanager has been finalized?

Tags: android, android-ndk, asset-management, illegalstateexception

I'm getting that exception when I pick a wallpaper. I'm actually not sure what function is the culprit. Here's the error log:

```
       I/ActivityManager( 1360): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.android.wallpaper.livepicker/.LiveWallpaperPreview (has extras) }
       W/dalvikvm(29175): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40020ac0)
       E/AndroidRuntime(29175): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
       E/AndroidRuntime(29175): java.lang.IllegalStateException: AssetManager has been finalized!
       E/AndroidRuntime(29175):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.isUpToDate(Native Method)
       E/AndroidRuntime(29175):     at android.app.ActivityThread.getPackageInfo(ActivityThread.java:2350)
       E/AndroidRuntime(29175):     at android.app.ActivityThread.getPackageInfoNoCheck(ActivityThread.java:2337)
       E/AndroidRuntime(29175):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2935)
       E/AndroidRuntime(29175):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3300(ActivityThread.java:125)
       E/AndroidRuntime(29175):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2087)
       E/AndroidRuntime(29175):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       E/AndroidRuntime(29175):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
       E/AndroidRuntime(29175):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
       E/AndroidRuntime(29175):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
       E/AndroidRuntime(29175):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
       E/AndroidRuntime(29175):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
       E/AndroidRuntime(29175):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
       E/AndroidRuntime(29175):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
       I/ActivityManager( 1360): Displayed activity com.android.wallpaper.livepicker/.LiveWallpaperPreview: 331 ms (total 331 ms)
       W/InputManagerService( 1360): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@44bf5a08
       I/ActivityManager( 1360): Process com.bukabros.videolivewallpaper (pid 29175) has died.
       W/ActivityManager( 1360): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.bukabros.videolivewallpaper/.VideoLiveWallpaper in 5000ms
       I/ActivityManager( 1360): Start proc com.bukabros.videolivewallpaper for service com.bukabros.videolivewallpaper/.VideoLiveWallpaper: pid=29207 uid=10090 gids={}
```

The only thing I can think of is that onCreate doesn't get called in the right order when the wallpaper gets picked cuz that's where I instantiate the asset manager.

And yes, I'm using the NDK but the asset manager doesn't get used there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah nevermind. The culprit was that the handle to the assetmanager was a static variable. (That was just a quick hack for something else). Making that a normal variable solved the problem.

Comment: What? What kind of variable was this? Sure, this was 5 years ago but I cannot find any other answers.